# Providing alias names to "related" table fields in Standard API using SOQL

Tags: soql, community, salesforce-id

When the below query is executed:

```
{{SWM4_Profile}}/services/data/v41.0/query/?q=SELECT+id+,+SWM_Role__c+,+SWM_Contact__r.Name+,+SWM_Contact__r.Email+FROM+SWM_Contact_Role__c+where+SWM_Role__c=+'SalesSupport'
```

i see results like:

```
{
    "totalSize": 3,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "SWM_Contact_Role__c",
                "url": "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/SWM_Contact_Role__c/aLf5B0000004CXZSA2"
            },
            "Id": "aLf5B0000004CXZSA2",
            "SWM_Role__c": "SalesSupport",
            "SWM_Contact__r": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Contact",
                    "url": "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0035B00000IMwvXQAT"
                },
                "Name": "Sales Support",
                "Email": "sales@mnc.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "SWM_Contact_Role__c",
                "url": "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/SWM_Contact_Role__c/aLf5B0000004CYmSAM"
            },
            "Id": "aLf5B0000004CYmSAM",
            "SWM_Role__c": "SalesSupport",
            "SWM_Contact__r": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Contact",
                    "url": "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0035B00000IeRFMQA3"
                },
                "Name": "s-support2",
                "Email": "abcd@gmail.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "SWM_Contact_Role__c",
                "url": "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/SWM_Contact_Role__c/aLf5B0000004CXeSAM"
            },
            "Id": "aLf5B0000004CXeSAM",
            "SWM_Role__c": "SalesSupport",
            "SWM_Contact__r": {
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "Contact",
                    "url": "/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/Contact/0035B00000ILQfOQAX"
                },
                "Name": "s-support",
                "Email": "dummy@abc.com"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want the JSON have the key "name", instead of Name, and "email" instead of "EMail". How do i format the query?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the API alter its output. It will always return the same capitalization as the field's API name as configured by the system. This is necessary because the API must preserve case sensitivity to avoid breaking integrations. If you want to do massage your output, you can do this manually, something like this:

```
function lowerkeys(x) {
  var r = {}
  Object.keys(x).forEach(
    k =>
    r[k.toLowerCase()] = (typeof x[k] == 'object'? lowerkeys(x[k]): x[k]))
  return r;
}
```

Which you would then call to fix your keys to lowercase:

```
var records = lowercase(result.records);
```